# Why is it not getting the data from the text file properly

Tags: java

It should be printing the average sleep score but it's still printing 0

Sample data from the file it is writing to
7.2 // 4 // Improvments: whatever
8.0 // 8 // Improvments: whatever
6.4 // 9 // Improvments: whatever
9.3 // 8 // Improvments: whatever
8.0 // 10 // Improvments: whatever
5.0 // 3 // Improvments: whatever
4.0 // 2 // Improvments: whatever
6.0 // 7 // Improvments: whatever

I tried to convert my double finding code I had earlier to integer code. The problem is for line 94 down

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inpart2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double ST;
    int q;
    String ip;
    Double av = 0.0;
    int av2 = 0;

    // Asks the user for their sleep time
    System.out.println("How many hours of sleep did you get last night?");
    ST = in.nextDouble();
    //Sleep quality 1-10
    System.out.println("Sleep quality 1-10");
    q = in.nextInt();
    if(q>10||q<0){
      System.out.println("Invalid input");
      q = in.nextInt();
    }
    //What could be improved
    System.out.println("What could be improved?");
    ip = inpart2.nextLine();

    //Print to text file
    try {
      FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("data.txt", true);
      myWriter.write("\n" + ST+ " // " + q + " // " + "Improvments: "+ ip);
      myWriter.close();
      System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Takes the most 7 most recent hours of sleep data and averages it
    //It can be found as it is seperated by the //
    //Print averge sleep over the past 7 days
    try {
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int lineCount = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lineCount++;
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println("Number of entires in the database: " + lineCount);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Print the 5 most recent entries in the database
try {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<Double> sleepTimes = new ArrayList<>();


    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("//", 2);
        String sleepTime = parts[0].trim();



        try {
            double sleepTimeDouble = Double.parseDouble(sleepTime);
            sleepTimes.add(sleepTimeDouble);


        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // Handle the case when the sleep time is not a valid double
        }


    }
    int startIndex = Math.max(0, sleepTimes.size() - 7);
    for (int i = startIndex; i < sleepTimes.size(); i++) {
      av += sleepTimes.get(i);
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}


    try {
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        ArrayList<Integer> sleepTimer = new ArrayList<>();


        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("//");
            String sleepTime = parts[0].trim();



            try {
                int sleepTimeint = Integer.parseInt(sleepTime);
                sleepTimer.add(sleepTimeint);


            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // Handle the case when the sleep time is not a valid double
            }


        }
        int startIndex = Math.max(0, sleepTimer.size() - 7);
        for (int w = startIndex; w < sleepTimer.size(); w++) {
          av2 += sleepTimer.get(w);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



System.out.println("You got " + String.format("%.2f", av/7)+ " on averge last week");
    System.out.println("With " + av2/7 + "/10 quality");



  }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? What did you find?

Comment: It didn't have any bugs it was an error I had with how I was reading the file. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is related to the way you are trying to parse the sleep time from the input file. In the section where you are reading the sleep times and trying to parse them into integers, you are using `Integer.parseInt(sleepTime)` to convert the sleep time to an integer.

The problem is that in your data file, the sleep times are stored as `doubles`, and trying to parse them as integers results in a `NumberFormatException`. This exception is caught, but it leads to the sleep time not being added to the sleepTimer list, and as a result, `av2 remains 0`.

To fix this issue, you should use Double.parseDouble instead of Integer.parseInt for parsing sleep times, as shown in the modified code snippet below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inpart2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double ST;
        int q;
        String ip;
        Double av = 0.0;
        int av2 = 0;

        // Asks the user for their sleep time
        System.out.println("How many hours of sleep did you get last night?");
        ST = in.nextDouble();
        
        // Sleep quality 1-10
        System.out.println("Sleep quality 1-10");
        q = in.nextInt();
        if (q > 10 || q < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            q = in.nextInt();
        }

        // What could be improved
        System.out.println("What could be improved?");
        inpart2.nextLine(); // Consume the newline character left by nextInt()
        ip = inpart2.nextLine();

        // Print to text file
        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("data.txt", true);
            myWriter.write("\n" + ST + " // " + q + " // " + "Improvements: " + ip);
            myWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Takes the most recent 7 hours of sleep data and averages it
        // It can be found as it is separated by the //
        // Print average sleep over the past 7 days
        try {
            File file = new File("data.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            ArrayList<Double> sleepTimes = new ArrayList<>();

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("//", 2);
                String sleepTime = parts[0].trim();

                try {
                    double sleepTimeDouble = Double.parseDouble(sleepTime);
                    sleepTimes.add(sleepTimeDouble);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    // Handle the case when the sleep time is not a valid double
                }
            }

            int startIndex = Math.max(0, sleepTimes.size() - 7);
            for (int i = startIndex; i < sleepTimes.size(); i++) {
                av += sleepTimes.get(i);
            }

            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Print the 5 most recent entries in the database
        try {
            File file = new File("data.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            ArrayList<Double> sleepTimer = new ArrayList<>();

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("//");
                String sleepTime = parts[0].trim();

                try {
                    double sleepTimeDouble = Double.parseDouble(sleepTime);
                    sleepTimer.add(sleepTimeDouble);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    // Handle the case when the sleep time is not a valid double
                }
            }

            int startIndex = Math.max(0, sleepTimer.size() - 7);
            for (int w = startIndex; w < sleepTimer.size(); w++) {
                av2 += sleepTimer.get(w).intValue();
            }

            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("You got " + String.format("%.2f", av / 7) + " on average last week");
        System.out.println("With " + av2 / 7 + "/10 quality");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It's still reading out of the leftmost column. I tried to make it only scan for ints but that didn't work. Is there any way i'm missing?

Comment: Please edit your question and  provide the ideal input and output you expect from your code. That should narrow it down so that we can fix it :)

Comment: By your question it's hard to make out what actually is your requirement (what you're passing in and what is to be expected by the program)